# Hibernate SerializationException

Tags: java, hibernate, deserialization, one-to-many, hibernate-onetomany

In my database, I have three tables: `Hotels`, `Facilities` and `Images`. Hotels table has "One to Many Relationship" with both tables: Facilities and Images. Facilities and Images table, both have hotels column as a Foreign Key.

While fetching details of a hotel, I want to retrieve Facilities and Images for the hotel. However I receive the  `org.hibernate.type.SerializationException`

Exception stacktrace:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize] with root cause
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 32303136
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:804)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:328)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:318)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:306)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.fromBytes(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:44)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2969)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.loadFromResultSet(EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.java:324)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.hydrateEntityState(EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.java:251)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.readRow(AbstractRowReader.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:693)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1897)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.forceInitialization(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:683)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.initializeNonLazyCollections(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:890)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:359)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2553)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2539)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2369)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2364)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
    at com.holidify.app.dao.impl.HotelsDaoImpl.getMergedResponse(HotelsDaoImpl.java:81)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy53.getMergedResponse(Unknown Source)
    at com.holidify.app.service.impl.HotelsServiceImpl.getHotelsMergedResponse(HotelsServiceImpl.java:104)
    at com.holidify.app.controller.HotelsController.searchDynamicHotels(HotelsController.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

> Hotels.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Hotels")
public class Hotels implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5573648649418161369L;
    private Set<Facilities> facilities;
    private Set<Images> images;
    private int hotelId;

    //other fields
    //other getter and setters

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "hotels")
    public Set<Images> getImages() {
        return images;
    }
    public void setImages(Set<Images> images) {
        this.images = images;
    }


    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "hotels")
    public Set<Facilities> getFacilities() {
        return facilities;
    }
    public void setFacilities(Set<Facilities> facilities) {
        this.facilities = facilities;
    }   
}
```

> Facilities.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Facilities")
public class Facilities implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -552767579935736531L;
    private Integer facilityId;
    private String facilityName;
    private Timestamp timeStamp;
    private Hotels hotels;


    //other getter and setters

    @Id
    @Column(name = "facilityId", insertable = true, updatable = true)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="hotelId")
    public Hotels getHotels() {
        return hotels;
    }
    public void setHotels(Hotels hotels) {
        this.hotels = hotels;
    }
    public Facilities() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public Facilities(String facilityName) {
        super();
        this.facilityName = facilityName;
    }   
}
```

> Images.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Images")
public class Images implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4318294155906543400L;

    private Integer imageId;
    private String imageURL;
    private Timestamp timeStamp;
    private Hotels hotels;

    //other getter and setters


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="hotelId")
    public Hotels getHotels() {
        return hotels;
    }
    public void setHotels(Hotels hotels) {
        this.hotels = hotels;
    }

    public Images() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public Images(String imageUrl) {
        super();
        this.imageURL = imageUrl;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15):

In some cases this error is also caused when you use JDK 8 java.time.LocalDateTime with hibernate and don't have a Converter for this registered. (This is not the case in the OP's question, but other people might stumble about this.)

Comment: You are right. I've had this error and the problem was a missing converter. The line 'java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 32303136' gives also a hint, that it might be here also a problem with the date as 32303136 is the ascii representation of 2016.

Comment: I use maven and added the following to solve this same issue:   <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Hibernate try to deserialize a column  that holds not serialized data. Hibernate thinks that this column has [`VARBINARY`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.0-en/binary-varbinary.html) format. I think it is `Timestamp` property or other object property. Try to comment all columns in `Facilities` and `Images` except `id` and `hotels`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use java SQL Date for date option and try again. Basically it happens sometimes when you try to convert date. So you can try with java SQL Date.